# Can adjectives in Japanese "stack" like in English?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Are both sentences below grammatically correct, and are they both used equally in conversation?

Stacked adjective:  あそこの奇麗な面白い人は、誰？

Non-stacked adjectives:  あそこの奇麗で面白い人は、誰？

Comment: Both sentences seem really unnatural but not in terms of the で vs な following the 形容動詞. Two points I'm pretty confident are wrong: (1) "彼処". Apparently, that can be read as あそこ but no one would write that in contemporary Japanese. (2) the final comma seems wrong (at least to me).

Several other features seem weird but I'm not as certain on those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can they stack? Yes.

頭がよくて、綺麗な彼女が欲しい。
綺麗な、頭がいい彼氏が欲しい。

But the more you stack, the heavier the sentence goes. Don't hesitate to break the sentence if you reach three.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen in even the easier-to-read newspapers and heard in various shows, it is allowable to stack adjectives like that. Although, the case may be that they are more colloquial.

Also, there are two ways to go about I-adjectives:

1. あそこの面白い、背が高い人は誰？
2. あそこの面白く、背が高い人は誰？

The second case is a mid form of ～くて and is frequently found in writing.

Comment: On the contrary, ～～くて is highly conversational.

Comment: I was talking about ～く by itself. I've never heard it in a conversation. On the other hand, I haven't heard every single Japanese dialog, so.. ^^